# ImportError: No Module name Multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, ironpython, importerror, python-c-extension

So I am using IronPython in PyDev and I am trying to import numpy. However, when I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dan\workspace\Practice\src\practice.py", line 8, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named multiarray
```

Is it because there is only a `multiarray.pyd` file instead of a `multiarray.py` file? What can I do about this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: One more thing, so import numpy works when I use it in the Python IDLE that comes with the python download, and I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can import the 'regular' numpy from IronPython (but it seems there's a port for IronPython you could use... http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net )